# Automatically forward a remote desktop connection to a new remote desktop connection?

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, windows-sbs-2008, windows-sbs

Is there any way to automatically redirect users which connect to a SBS 2008 to another server using same credentials?

For example, I’ve two servers: **mainserver** and **applicationserver**. There is not external access to the **applicationserver** so I was wondering if there was a possibility to automatic open a remote desktop connection to it from the **mainserver**. So if the user **johndoe** connects thru a remote desktop to the **mainserver** he will automatically be forwarded to the **applicationserver** with the same username and password he used to connect to the **mainserver**.

The mainserver is running SBS 2008 by the way.

I hope I’ve described the scenario correctly otherwise please let me know and I’ll try to explain it better.

Sincerely
Mestika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the built in functionallity of the RWW (Remote Web Workplace) in SBS? Configure the user to be allowed to connect remotely to the application server (configured in the SBS console) then when the user logs in to the RWW web site and chooses the "Connect to a Computer" option, they'll see the application server in the list and can connect to it via RDP from the RWW.

Comment: Hi Joe, thank you so much for your answer and advice, I had totally forgot that and this will help me a great deal. Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help...